# Adjusting cell height in tables wider than a full page

Tags: tables

Suppose there is a table too wide to fit on a page. What you can do in this case is to print the table on multiple pages, such that it can be seen side-by-side, by using multiple table environments and separating these with page breaks.

Given these column definitions:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

Table code for a 2-page wide table is akin to:

```
\begin{longtable}{|L{80pt}|L{80pt}|}
\hline
header 1 & header 2 \\
\hline
value 11 this is a much longer value which causes issues by overflowing into another line and misaligning this table with the other table & value 12 \\
value 21 & value 22 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\pagebreak
\begin{longtable}{|L{80pt}|L{80pt}|}
\hline
header 3 & header 4 \\
\hline
value 13 & value 14 \\
value 23 & value 24 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

Note that the values are variable. In essence, 'any reasonably long text' could be inside each cell.

This works and aligns as long as within the set of all the values there are no values which span multiple lines, e.g. no cells with line breaks. However, as soon as there are cells with line breaks, these line breaks will only appear in their respective table.

How does one go about aligning the tables? E.g. in table i, column j set its column height to be at least the maximum of the column heights of all the tables for column j.

Comment: Are you sure this design of a table should be implemented? Is there no other option (e.g. sidewaystable) for you?

Comment: it is impossible to see from your fragment (or even run your fragment) ut why do you need the columns to be 80pt wide? just making that value  woudl work for the text shown

Comment: Please fix your example so that it demonstrates the issue. Your text describes "cells with line breaks" being the problem but you give no indication of the definition of `L` column nor show any cells with a line break. Do you mean forced line breaks (from `\newline` ?) or automatic line breaks from long text?   Your example should be complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{docuemnt}` and demonstrate the issue.

Comment: one last question, why are you using `longtable` if you are ending each table within one page and forcing a page break outside the table?

Comment: The question does not concern 'this specific table' but rather 'ANY' table. You can suppose that the TeX code is machine-generated, and the table contents as well as no. of columns, no. of rows, and row/column widths are variables. I could make the example a really large table that demonstrates the desync issues but I don't want solutions that only fix that example (by say adding manual line breaks).

Comment: Speaking for myself, I think your plan to break up a wide table (which, presumably, has a lot of columns) in the manner you're proposing is highly questionable. (I actually have a much stronger, more damning characterization in mind, but it's not printable.) You ought to be thinking of creating separate standalone tables, with each table presumably having a common left-hand column and a small number of data columns.

Comment: Sharing the first column and putting a 'counter' in that column that lists row numbers is my current solution to this problem. Of course, that doesn't stop the output's user from asking me to align the table rows because other output formats allow it (think spreadsheets).
Note that the example does use multiple tables already to break up the wide table.

Comment: whether you want an answer for general or this specific table it is still good to provide a test file, it clarifies the question and makes it much easier for people to test possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a two page tabular and display half at a time using `\adjustbox`.  Figuring out where the gap is could pose a problem.  I also threw in some code to start the two pages on a even page.

BTW, I am not familiar with column type L, so used p instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newsavebox{\twopage}

\newcommand{\evenpage}{\ifodd\value{page}\afterpage{\evenpage}%
  \else
    \hspace*{\fill}\adjustbox{Clip=0pt 0pt {0.5\width} 0pt}{\usebox{\twopage}}
    \newpage
    \adjustbox{Clip={0.5\width} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\usebox{\twopage}}
    \newpage
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\twopage}{\begin{tabular}
{|p{80pt}|p{80pt}|@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|p{80pt}|p{80pt}|}
\hline
header 1 & header 2 & header 3 & header 4 \\
\hline
value 11 & value 12 & value 13 & value 14 \\
value 21 & value 22 & value 23 & value 24 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}%
\evenpage
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

---

I thought I would try to make this more like a table, including a caption split over two pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only
%\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool
\usepackage{caption}

\newsavebox{\twopage}
\newsavebox{\twopagecaption}
\newlength{\twopagecaptionht}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}%
{\newcommand\makecaption[2]{%
  {\captionlabelfont #1}%
  {\caption@iflf\captionlabelfont\relax\caption@lsep}%
  {\captiontextfont
    \caption@ifstrut
      {\vrule\@height\ht\strutbox\@width\z@}%
      {}%
    \nobreak\hskip\z@skip % enable hyphenation
    \caption@tfmt{#2}%
    \caption@ifstrut
      {\ifhmode\@finalstrut\strutbox\fi}%
      {}%
  }%
}}%
{}

\newcommand{\splitcaption}[2][\empty]% #1 = short caption (optional), #2 = caption
{\setbox\twopagecaption=\vbox{\parindent=0pt
  \refstepcounter{table}%
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \addcontentsline{lot}{table}%
      {\protect\numberline{\thetable}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{lot}{table}%
      {\protect\numberline{\thetable}{\ignorespaces #1}}%
  \fi
  \let\vskip=\@gobble
  \@ifundefined{makecaption}{}{\let\@makecaption=\makecaption}%
  \@makecaption{\fnum@table}{\ignorespaces #2}%
\par}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\evenpage}{\clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\afterpage{\evenpage}%
  \else
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
      \hspace*{\fill}\adjustbox{Clip=0pt 0pt {0.5\width} 0pt}{\usebox{\twopage}}\par
      \vskip\abovecaptionskip
      \twopagecaptionht=\dimexpr \ht\twopagecaption + \dp\twopagecaption\relax
      \dimen0=\dimexpr 0.5\twopagecaptionht + 0.5\baselineskip\relax
      \setbox0=\vsplit\twopagecaption to \dimen0
      \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht\twopagecaption + \dp\twopagecaption\relax
      \advance\twopagecaptionht by -\dimen0
      \ifdim\twopagecaptionht<\dimen0 \twopagecaptionht=\dimen0\fi
      \vbox to \twopagecaptionht {\unvbox0\vfill}%
      \global\twopagecaptionht=\twopagecaptionht
    \end{minipage}\par
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
      \adjustbox{Clip={0.5\width} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\usebox{\twopage}}\par
      \vskip\abovecaptionskip
      \vbox to \twopagecaptionht {\unvbox\twopagecaption\vfill}%
    \end{minipage}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\savebox{\twopage}{\begin{tabular}
{|p{80pt}|p{80pt}|@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|p{80pt}|p{80pt}|}
\hline
header 1 & header 2 & header 3 & header 4 \\
\hline
value 11 & value 12 & value 13 & value 14 \\
value 21 & value 22 & value 23 & value 24 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}%
\splitcaption[short caption]{\blindtext}%
\afterpage{\evenpage}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I understand how to extend this to three, four, etc. pages as well; by replacing the `0.5\width` argument by  x * `0.333\width`, `0.25\width`, and so on. E.g. the 4th page on a 6-page wide table would use 0.5\width and 0.667\width as its left- and right- clip boundaries.
Remains getting rid of the artifacts at the table edge. But I think using the more detailed lines from the booktabs package should do the trick. (e.g. `\cmidrule` and friends).

Comment: Actually, since this is a clip it would go .667\width, .75\width, etc.  Are you sure this is a good idea?